Anythingslider broken after Time.ly calendar update
My site is using Anythingslider on the homepage and is now only showing the images as a stack. I don't see an error in the code. Does anyone have a suggestion on what to fix?
view-source:https://storytellingwithsaris.com
I tried turning off the calendar plugin and searching the Anythingslider code. There is no access to it on the dashboard or plugin list. I also tried searching here for similar questions.
